# External game with Loader doesn't work in Flash, Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript, flash, embed, loader

I'd like to load a 3rd party game into my own swf so I can take a picture of it. I'm using the standard `flash.display.Loader` class for the loading part.

Example of a 3rd party game: http://andkon.com/arcade/adventureaction/megaminer/megaminer.swf

[Embedding](http://jsbin.com/iwabib/1/) it inside an html document seems to work fine, but not with the `Loader`.

So it obviously works in one case, there has to be a way to load it with ActionScript the same way a simple html `<embed>` does.

There are no error messages, `Event.COMPLETE` fires, but the game is stuck at the loading screen.

*(Sidenotes: I have a working script that loads some games perfectly, but there are ones like this that won't load properly. I also have a a proxy set up in PHP to get around cross-origin permission errors)*

Comment: Curious to know what actually happens: do you get errors, does the loader say it loaded the content, etc.

Comment: Potentially they don't want you to do this and have code in place to prevent you from doing this, but they've probably done something like use Singletons or referenced the root which would cause it not to load in your swf. Or it's just a different version of Actionscript, which probably isn't compatible.

Comment: @SunilD. I can't see any error messages and `Event.COMPLETE` fires for the loader. But the game doesn't start it's just stuck with the loading screen. Basically looks the same like when you go the the URL in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it's loading just fine (when you link directly to the game, it stays at the loading screen anyway, which suggests that's the right behavior).

<strike>So the problem isn't with the loading, it's to do with the wrapper you're loading it into. When you view it on whichever website is hosted, chances are you're looking at a wrapper swf which is loading that game into it - and as per the guidelines of the site hosting it,  the wrapper swf will call a *start* function or something similar to kick it off. You'd need to see what needs to be called on the swf to start it.</strike>

You might be able to look on a site where it's being hosted and see if they publicly give out their guidelines for game devs, but I had a little glance around and it doesn't look like they do.

Or you could decompile the wrapper swf and see what function it's calling... Though I don't promise they'd be okay with you doing that.

---

So there's no wrapper swf... Perhaps the game is doing a check to see if its width and height match a predefined size before it begins?